# SharePoint 2010: Set character limit of news webpart without SP Designer?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, character, limit

The SharePoint 2010 news/announcement webpart cuts off messages after 250 characters. I would like to set a higher character limit.

All solutions I have found so far involve SharePoint Designer which is not allowed in my company.

Is there a way to modify the character limit without using SharePoint Designer?

Comment: There are a couple of other methods, however, they would require a level of permissions similar to that of a SharePoint Designer user. You'll need someone else to this for you I'm afraid.